# Why is my application not catching any data from Firebase?

Tags: java, android, firebase

I am working on my login screen.

However, when I run the code after filling both ID and pw, the userId (code below) is still null.

```
foundUser = dataSnapshot.getValue(User.class);
userId = foundUser.getId();
userPw = foundUser.getPw();
```

My application is definitely connected to the Firebase. However, when I debug the code, I can see
    W/ClassMapper: No setter/field for exampleuserID found on class com.example.hellobook.User

Comment: Please provide your database Structure and Why you assigned variables for Database Reference ?

Comment: @Ashish My user database contains boolean admin / firstName / id / lastName / numBookReports / pw and I just assigned it because I thought it might be useful in some degrees

Comment: Please post the Screenshot so we can understand the problem properly.

Comment: @Ashish I posted it

Answer (score 2):

Shouldn't this

```
for (DataSnapshot ds : dataSnapshot.getChildren()) { 
    foundUser = dataSnapshot.getValue(User.class);
```

be

```
for (DataSnapshot ds : dataSnapshot.getChildren()) { 
    foundUser = ds.getValue(User.class);
```

Comment: Good catch yogourt!

Comment: Thank you for catching that and I modified my code, but it still does not work :((

Answer (score 1):

You have put wrong Reference of Database.

```
DatabaseReference ref = database.getReference().child("hellobookdatabase").child("User").child(id);
```

Now you need make little changes in your Condition.

```
ref.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
    @Override
    public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
        foundUser = dataSnapshot.getValue(User.class);
        userId = foundUser.getId();
        userPw = foundUser.getPw();
        if (userId!=null && userId.equals(id)) {
            if (userPw.equals(psw)) {
                startActivity(new Intent(LoginScreen.this, LandingScreen.class));
            }
        }
        else {
            Toast.makeText(LoginScreen.this, "Wrong ID or password. Try again", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }

        }
    }
    @Override
    public void onCancelled (DatabaseError error) {
        @NonNull DatabaseError databaseError;                        }
});
```

The reason Why your query not working :

1. Your reference wasn't proper.
2. Your valueEventlistener was searching user id in **hellobookdatabase** instead of **User** child.

Any other query related to this just Comment down.

Comment: Thanks a lot!! I think it helped. However, I still cannot run my code from  `ref.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
` to `Toast.makeText(LoginScreen.this, "Wrong ID or password. Try again", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();`. Neither intent nor toast is launched. Why is it?

Comment: @purpleccherry can you log the id your trying to match and provide the same id your using in db

Comment: When I try to log in with the correct id and password, the log just says `D/EGL_emulation: eglMakeCurrent: 0xe9cdffc0: ver 3 0 (tinfo 0xe2510640)`, and this is all I can see (no other code is made)

Comment: @purplecherry please join [stackoverflow chat room](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/198592/helping-others). so comment section won't be messy.

Answer (score 0):

Try
Change this
DatabaseReference ref = database.getReference("User")